# jsonapi-resources: MySQL Error - 0.10.x, 0.11.0.beta2, Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

Jsonapi-resources: MySQL Error - 0.10.x, 0.11.0.beta2

- Rails: 7.0.8
- mysql2: 0.5.5
- jsonapi-resources: 0.10.x, 0.11.0.beta2

We tried to implement jsonapi-resources into our project with MySQL DB. Firstly we tried a demo (https://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/basic_usage.html) example from the documentation and we immediately got this MySQL error:

```
"exception": "Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.\"id\" AS \"contacts_id\", `contacts`.`id` FROM `contacts` ORDER BY contacts.id asc' at line 1",
```

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include JSONAPI::ActsAsResourceController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

**resources:**

```
class ContactResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :name_first, :name_last, :email, :twitter
  has_many :phone_numbers
end


class PhoneNumberResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :name, :phone_number
  has_one :contact
  filter :contact
end
```

**models:**

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phone_numbers
  validates :name_first, presence: true
  validates :name_last, presence: true
end

class PhoneNumber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

**routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  jsonapi_resources :contacts
  jsonapi_resources :phone_numbers
end
```

**If we downgrade to jsonapi-resources 0.9.12 everything works just fine.**

Comment: Looks like improper delimited identifiers. I don't use Rails or jsonapi, but searching their github I found this merge into v0.11-dev: https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/pull/1400 So I guess the fix hasn't been released yet. You should continue to use 0.9.12 until the next release of 0.11.